# Why am I getting an error while trying to install rasa in python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, ras

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 1.13.2 requires tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0, but you have tensorboard 2.4.1 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 1.13.2 requires tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.4.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: Certain Versions of packages are incompatible with others. So, in this case I would recommend creating a virtual environment and add all the required packages if you don't want to downgrade your current version of tensorflow.

Comment: From the message, it appears you would have to downgrade your tensorboard and tensorflow-estimator packages. To avoid that, it is probably better to install rasa in a virtual environment instead.

Comment: Its expected to install Tensorflow version 2.4. Run pip install tensorflow==2.4.0. Thanks!